# Updating ASP.Net WebApp during people are working

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, updates

I want to know how can i update a ASP.Net webapp during people are working on it?

best reguards,
Kevin

Comment: Whenever you change dll (code) or web.config the application will restart. If you are using sessions and validating it on all page requests your users will get disrupted. If you are asking how to avoid server down time, please make it clear in the question.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the app. Once you make changes to the bin with updated dll's the application will restart. It depends on how much of a disruption the application restart will have.